# How to manage aws autoscaling with puppet

Tags: puppet

how to manage auto scaling instances with puppet? i want to configure s/w stack based on type of instances (e.g if web then Apache or Nginx and if app then java or php)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily managed with hiera. On bootstrap of the server, you can write a custom fact which hiera will use to apply the relevant modules to your server. In your cloud-init user data script you can add something like this:

```
echo 'role=apache_web' > /etc/facter/facts.d/role.txt
```

You can then use that role in hiera's hierarchy. Here is an example section for `hiera.yml`:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "environment/%{::environment}"
  - "role/%{::server_role}"
  - "common"
```

Your hiera file for you apache_web role would be `hieradata/role/apache_web.yaml` in your control repo. For Puppet 4, the absolute path should be `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/$ENVIRONMENT/hieradata/role/apache_web.yaml`. Here is an example:

```
---
classes:
  - 'apache'
  - 'myinternalmodule'
```

To tie everything together, have all of your nodes use the same site.pp which includes:

```
hiera_include('classes')
```